# Bootstrap modal show error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap for my website design and angular to communicate with the server. 
The problem I am having is that whenever I try to open a bootstrap modal I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=]

This is the button tag:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="post()">Register</button>
```

And the angular scope:

```
$scope.registerAction = function() {
  $('#registerModal').modal('show')
}
```

What is strange is that if I open a browser console and enter

`$('#registerModal').modal('show');`

It works

Comment: Could you post the code for the modal window #registerModal? Thanks

Comment: Where's the code for `$scope.post`..?

Comment: the button is                     <li><a href="#" ng-click="registerAction()">Register</a> I copied something else by mistake

Comment: Try to reproduce it in a jsfiddle and post it here.

Comment: Also, try using the [Angular-UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). It is bad practice to run jQuery within your angularJS.